# Spelling Suggestions showing 'None' haystack

Tags: django, solr, spell-checking, django-haystack

Getting "None" for spelling suggestions.

settings.py contains 'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True

search_indexes.py

```
class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='post_type',faceted=True)
    job_location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_location',faceted=True)
    job_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_type',faceted=True)
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name',faceted=True)
    job_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_title', faceted=True)
    start_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='start_date', faceted=True)
    end_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='end_date', faceted=True)
    job_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_description', faceted=True)
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country', faceted=True)
    suggestions = indexes.CharField()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super(JobIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        prepared_data['suggestions'] = prepared_data['text']
        return prepared_data

    def get_model(self):
        return jobpost
```

rebuilded index many times.

solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">suggestions</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker1</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

    </lst>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

schema.xml contains suggestions field

```
<field name="suggestions" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
```

Can anyone tell why it is showing 'None'?

Comment: Which haystack version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it working with the demo app.

Here is my demo app, includes solr conf files.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43002805/mysite.zip

Here is what I am using.

Django 1.5.1

Haystack 2.0

Solr 4.3.0

First add sample data through admin interface.
Then build solr schema using

> python manage.py build_solr_schema > path/to/solr/conf/dir/schema.xml

Start Solr java server

> python manage.py rebuild_index

If rebuild_index gives error regarding *version* field then add this to schema.xml fields tag

After rebuilding index you have to hit this URL once to build spell suggestions dictionary

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=tes&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

> python manage.py runserver

Try it using localhost:8000/jobs

Change search query from views.py based on your sample data

Comment: I would like to see your search template where you are using spell suggestions.

Comment: i am displaying them like this {{ suggestion }}

Comment: actually i am using the default search form..n i don't have any view..do i need to write my own view?

Comment: Ideally, default search form should also work, check what query it sends to solr when you use the default search form. You can check it on solr server terminal window

Comment: no,tried everything but still showing 'None'..anyways thank u so much for all the help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32007/discussion-between-abdul-haseeb-and-madeeha-ameer)